# return of spellbinder python need

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to make the return of spellbinder program from HP Codewars 2012, and I have no idea what I'm doing. here's what i have so far please help. I am using python 3.3.0. here is the link http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw15/problems/2012ProblemsFinalForPrinting.pdf

```
def  fix (string):
'''The function of the repaired by a
speelbot abused Dictionary

word -> word to be repaired
a -> the point-to-exchange
b -> the correct letter

'''
    word, a, b =  string.split ( " " )

    return  word.replace (a, b)


for  word in  [ '"MUSTARD MC " , "JUNK J TR" , "MONSTER ON A" ']:
    print (word, "->" to repair (word))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! From your question, I have no idea what this code is supposed to do.

Comment: Currently you're splitting a string on nothing and expecting a list of 3. And you have mismatching quotes in your list of strings for the for loop. You'll need to be much more specific with the issue and your goal.

Comment: You're close first you need to split on space not "", so split(" "), make sure your string are open and closed correctly, ' and " are not interchangeable for opening and closing. And you mistyped words on your replace line.

Comment: is this right? @denmat

Comment: run it and see what you get. It's close but you're still missing the last bit. The error you get will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Hint: your 2 last line have issues. 2 Issues are related to strings and one to the name of your function and how you're calling it.

Comment: it keeps sayoing expected an indented block @denmat

Comment: @dennmat still not working

Answer (score 0):

Didn't want to do this.

You should look into trying to debug and figuring stuff out.

```
def fix(item):
    '''The function of the repaired by a
    speelbot abused Dictionary

    word -> word to be repaired
    a -> the point-to-exchange
    b -> the correct letter

    '''
    try:
        word, a, b = item.split(" ")
    except ValueError:
        print "Invalid Input"

    return word.replace(a, b)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for w in ["MUSTARD M C", "JUNK J TR", "MONSTER ON A"]:
        print w, "-> ", fix(w)
```